# How to place an array of elements inside a function with ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

```
 var answered = ["john","jay","mark"];

 function tick(){

   $("#btn_wys").on('click', function(){

     var name = $('input#name').val();
     var num = $('input#num').val();

     if ($.trim(name)!= ''){
       $.post('wys.php', {name: name, num: num},function(data){
          $('div#name-data').text(data);
     });
    }
 }
```

How will I pass the array "answered" such that variables name, num, and answered will be read on the wys.php using ajax.

inside wys.php is a query that will echo 1 or 0.

additional question: will I be able to add new element inside the array 'answered' if wys.php echoes 1 ? If yes, how?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but can't you just add an extra parameter in the data you're posting, like {name: name, num: num, answers: answer} ?
Also, I believe you have a missing closing brace for the if statement.

Comment: you can stringify the array like : `{name: name, num: num, answered:JSON.strigify(answered)}`, then in php, read it as `json_decode($_POST['answered'])`

Comment: _"additional question: will I be able to add new element inside the array 'answered' if wys.php echoes 1 ? If yes, how?"_ What should be added to array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is all you need

```
var answered = ["john","jay","mark"];

//run function 
tick(answered);

function tick(answered){ // pass in function
  answered.push('Smith'); //insert new
  alert(answered[0]); // get the value number 1 in array
  alert(answered[1]); // get the value number 2 in array
  alert(answered[2]); // get the value number 3 in array
  alert(answered[3]); // get the value number 4 in array
  alert(answered.length); // how many values in array
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/82zmcbuw/1/)

to pass it in php

```
{name: name, num: num , answered : answered}
```

and in php read it as array

```
<?php
 print_r($_POST['answered']);
?>
```

Comment: glad to hear that .. Good Luck :)